# Halting data inserts for future refresh of post?

Tags: database

I am hacking a plugin to add a feature I need. I have created this code which works:

```
if(!$active && $current_price < $start_price){
    add_post_meta ( $postid,'auction_no_bid','1', true );
} else if(!$active && $current_price >= $start_price){
    add_post_meta ( $postid,'auction_bid','1', true );  } else {
    echo 'i got nuthin';
}
```

When a timer completes its one time cycle, the code executes. If I refresh the browser afterwards, or if a visitor has a look at the post, the code executes again since the timer cycle has done its job.

Nothing is inserted in the database on subsequent executions of course, because the data is already there.

But I would like to prevent the redundant database action on future page loads if possible. Since once the data is there, all is well.

Is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've discovered the trigger is actually the loading of the page. So Disregard please.

I will need to dig further and have the timer do the triggering :)

Thanks!